# Tab character in Java

Tags: java, swing, menu

Trying to get a tab character into a `JMenuItem` using `\t` but it's not printing.

I bet it's something really basic I'm missing. Here's the code

```
menuItem = new JMenuItem("New\tCtrl + N");
```

Thanks

Comment: This should probably be tagged under Swing too!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
menuItem = new JMenuItem("New");
menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
```

You should also add mnemonics for usability:

```
menuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_N);
```

See the [Java Look and Feel Guidelines](http://java.sun.com/products/jlf/) for greater clarification, especially [volume 1](http://java.sun.com/products/jlf/ed2/book/index.html).

Comment: Alternative: `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control N")`

Answer (score 5):

You're not supposed to add keyboard shortcuts manually, there's an API for it, that puts them in the proper place. [Look here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jfc/ch03_08.htm), for instance, or search the Swing docs for "accelerators".